# Precision and recall at AWS Autopilot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I've run an automl job at AWS Autopilot using the F1 metric. I'd like to see the value of precision and recall too. How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the algo used, they might be visible in the training log of the top candidate.

What you could also do is keep a test set on the side, and use it to compute precision, recall and other metrics on the trained model.

Comment: That's precisely what I did later: keep a test set and evaluate. It solved my problem. Thank you.